# Insert Content between two HTML comment lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say for example you have the following setup:

```
<div class="blah"><!--start--><!-- stop --></div>
```

I was wondering how one would go about inserting content **between** the "start" & "stop" html comment lines?

I have found this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022029/getting-text-between-two-html-comments-into-a-javascript-variable) to be somewhat useful, and I managed to get my content to load, but it keeps on loading it below the "stop" comment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you create a div between start and stop, and then append the content to it?

Comment: Is there a pattern in your html we can see?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769964/can-you-use-jquery-to-add-comments-dynamically-to-code this will help you out

Comment: What would be the practical use for this?

Comment: If you are dynamically inserting content, why does it matter if it loads below the stop comment, or above it?  How would that affect anything else you're doing?

Comment: @everyone Well, that may be used as placeholders in big, for example, paragraph tag. Why do you all think this is useless?

Comment: @dbanet The div essentially marks the start and end of the content, all the comment does is explicitly say the same thing. I don't think it really would improve readability of the HTML - especially since it is absolutely meaningless for the actual source, and only makes a little sense when you inspect the DOM.

Comment: @Gray look, you have a `<p>with damn lot of text</p>`, I mean, a real paragraph, e. g., from a book. And you wanna have placeholders in it. What would you do? Insert a `<div>` with `style:display:inline-block`? That is silly, cuz it creates an another DOM element. Waste of memory. While you can once go thru the text with script and insert text in placeholders. No waste of memory, and, probably, works faster in overall.

Comment: @dbanet I may be misunderstanding your scenario, but it sounds like I would just put the `<p>` inside the div. The div is already there. The comment just wraps the content. I don't need a comment to mark the end of it, because the div it is inside marks the end of it. Doesn't matter how big the `<p>` is. Can you maybe make a jsfiddle to illustrate what value the comments add?

Comment: @Gray who said the comments mark the start and the end **of a div**? They mark **where should some content be inserted**. So, you may have `<p>some text, where some <!--another text--><!--another text/--> may be inserted in the middle of it, asynchronously (hope I've written this word right</p>`. For exmaple, you have one million of these placeholders :) I don't think a tab with one million DOM elements would survive, while you can easily go thru the `p.innerHTML` and insert the needed text in the placeholder.

Comment: if you really want this for placeholders for a huge paragraph, why not using anchor tags that would also allow your visitors to navigate through that paragraph quicker in addition for you to recognize them in source? in terms of what is faster and slower - any single empty element you add to page will take approximately the same time in most browsers, as they all call the same API function of the browser (see here: http://jsperf.com/difference-between-adding-various-elements-to-page)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter well, I don't think html comments create dom elements (fast googling "do html comments create dom elements" gave nothing), could anyone answer this question? So, it would eat less memory than `<span>`'s in the text. **All that I want to say, don't blame the question's author -- you don't know why should he need this, and, probably, he knows better**.

Comment: @dbanet I was not blaming the author, only trying to be helpful providing an alternative solution - like everyone here... I believe that's what comments are for. If we knew an answer, we'd post it as an answer or "quick Googled it"

Comment: @dbanet "who said the comments mark the start and end of a div?" The example in the question says that. I feel like you are looking for a way to make sense of this, but the asker isn't inserting a million placeholders, and if he was I doubt a million AJAX requests is the right way to do it. All we see is one comment with one div. Any speculation otherwise is pointless. We are getting off-topic. If you can quickly throw together a jsfiddle which illustrates the value of this, and perhaps add it to your answer, I would appreciate it. But this conversation is too theoretical.

Comment: @Gray why will I do this? To protect my point? Ha. I am too lazy. Also, you don't know what does author think, you do only know **how did you understand what author wrote**.

Comment: @Gray to protect the point of misunderstanding, the author just got the answer **he wanted**. And also I don't think he needs to justify why he wants what he wants to get an answer.

Comment: Although there is a node type for comments in DOM, relying on them for any kind of logic is a delicate matter. Maybe with HTML you might(!) be fine, but for XHTML (OK, no one uses that any more) it is explicitly defined that the parser might disregard comments and actually throw them away while building the DOM.

Comment: @CBroe thanks. Too good I use XHTML. Also, a good amount of XHTML-features were implemented in HTML5, so it may be interesting to test if there is a corresponding DOM element for an HTML comment with `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: @dbanet Sorry, I am having a little trouble understanding your wording. I think I get most of what you mean though. The reason it is acceptable to probe askers for more details and question their reasons is that sometimes, they are asking the wrong question. Read about the [X-Y Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). It is not that they have to "justify" themselves, it is that they (and future visitors) can learn and improve from discussing their reasoning. I feel like you see questions as an attack - this is not a good attitude to have on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Gray that is as probable, as that there is no "XY problem" or the author asks about X. You can't proof neither the first, nor the second.

Comment: @dbanet Sorry. I think you've misunderstood what the X-Y problem is. It is not about proving X or Y. Please re-read the link, and consider my previous comments if you are interested in understanding what I said. This is now clutter on the question, so I am not going to comment anymore.

Comment: @Gray no, I've understand the XY problem quite good. Just don't try to see more than there is.

Comment: @NikitaSingh - Im loading content from another html file.

Comment: @dbanet - I am using it for a long piece of content, yes. I have project that runs over 80+ html pages. Now, I'm using Notepad++ and without a template system (such as the one Dreamweaver has for example), its a **>>insert multiple swearwords here<<** nightmare to change something in the navigation menu. This method allows me to create my own template system by creating an html file containing all my static elements, such as the menus, etc... Chenge one, change all! :)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter - As mentioned ^ here above, it is for long content but loaded externally... Just makes my life easier!

Comment: @andi - Because of the type of content it is, location matters a great deal... to me atleast. I use Notepad++ which does not have the template functionality of Dreaweaver for example, and this method allows me to use a template system... Albeit unorthodox, it works.

Comment: @Sergio - This [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ln6rV/) by j08691 sums it up. Only the content os loaded form an external html file and dropped between the lines so to say.

Comment: @CBroe - I normally stick to html, but is there a way to make sure if its reliable or not (I am using HTML5)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('.blah').contents().filter(function () {
     return this.nodeType == 8;
 }).first().after('test');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ln6rV/)**

Returns:

```
<div class="blah">
    <!--start-->test<!-- stop -->
</div>
```

Comment: @dbanet - what do you mean?

Comment: The code above will insert your content after the first comment ( `nodeType == 8` ), not necessarily between `<!--start-->` and `<!--stop-->`

Comment: @dbanet - did I say you were?

Comment: Reread the code and got it... I really have to discover jQuery :)

Comment: @shshaw - it returns the comment nodes for the blah classed element, exactly as the OP specified. It's not a catch-all.

Comment: @j08691 nope, just to be sure :)

Comment: The question was recently edited so it may not have been there originally, but Reinhardt asked specifically for "inserting content between the 'start' & 'stop' html comment lines". Given the example code, yours will work but I think targeting the specific comment line would be more bulletproof.

Comment: @j08691 - You sir (or madam, i have not checked your profile) are the genius of the lantern! with a bit of tweaking it works like a dream.

Comment: @j08691 - How can I specify what comment pair im looking for? As in my original example at the top: If I want to add certain content to the  `<!-- start --> <!-- end -->` pair and different content to the `<!-- bloop --> <!-- bleep -->` pair.

Comment: You can change the `.first()` to `.eq()`, which is zero-based. So for example, after the first would be `.eq(0)`, after the second would be `.eq(1)` etc.

Comment: @Reinhardt If you're interested in targeting a specific comment, you can use `this.nodeValue` to test what the content of the comment is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/Ln6rV/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'll hardcode this:

```
var content="Insert me in:)";
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('blah'),function(e){
    e.innerHTML=e.innerHTML.split('start--><!--stop')[0]+"start-->"
               +content+
               "<!--stop"+e.innerHTML.split('start--><!--stop')[1];
});
```

Comment: Ahh, sorry, "jQuery" badge... should I rewrite this more bulls^WjQueryish?

Comment: How would you (with this method) pull in content from an external html file? Say you had a div in another file called "bleh", how would you go about? Would you define a variable that points to that file and div like `var $main = $('flooz/flaz.html #container_burp .bleh')` ?

Answer (score 0):

This will insert your content after `<!--start-->`

```
var newContent = "<strong>New!</strong>",
    mergedContent = $('.blah').html().replace("<!--start-->","<!--start-->"+newContent);
$('.blah').html(mergedContent);
```

Comment: Thing is I don't want to replace the comments, I just wish to add content between the two comments. If I understand this correctly `.replace("<!--start-->","<!--start-->"+newContent);` means: Replace `<!-- start -->` with `<!-- start -->`and the new content as defined above? Wont it be possible to just find the `<!-- start -->` comment and drop in the content after that?

Comment: You're replacing `<!--start-->` with `<!--start-->` plus the new content which has the same result as inserting after. This will not affect the placement of `<!--start-->` in the DOM. Will you not know what the exact comment will be?