# How To Wrap Tag In Comment In Javascript,Or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Want To Wrap My IN Comment 
I Want To Disable Some Tags and Scripts In Run Time,

```
<div id="some-div">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150"/>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/330"/>
</div>

$(function ()
{
    $('img').wrap('<!---></--->');
});
```

But They Don't Wrap They Delete My Tag
See Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/p8nbpt7o/1/

Comment: Nice question, actually. But it's already been answered.

Comment: Sorry Dear I Find Many Times In Google But I Cant Find Perfect Answer

Comment: You can refer this URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769964/can-you-use-jquery-to-add-comments-dynamically-to-code (OR) You can use this jQuery Plugin : http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jquery-comments-plug-in-to-access-html-comments-for-dom-templating.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can create comment node using **[`document.createComment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createComment)** and replace `img` with comment node using **[`replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)**

```js
$('img').each(function() {
  parent = this.parentNode;
  parent.replaceChild(document.createComment(this.outerHTML), this);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-div">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/330" />
</div>
```

or you can use **[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)** in jQuery

```js
$('img').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith(document.createComment(this.outerHTML));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-div">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/330" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Directly in HTML

HTML comments start with `<!--` and end with `-->`.

If you want to comment all your tags together in your HTML, you could do it like this :

```
<!--
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150"/>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/350/330"/>
-->
```

If you want to comment all your tags individually in your HTML, you could do it like this :

```
<!--<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">-->
<!--<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150">-->
<!--<img src="http://placekitten.com/350/330">-->
```

---

### With jQuery

If you want to do it with jQuery, you can use `replaceWith` instead of `wrap` :

```
$(function(){
    $('img').replaceWith(function() {
        return "<!--" + this.outerHTML + "-->";
    });
});
```

Result :

```
<!--<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">-->
<!--<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150">-->
<!--<img src="http://placekitten.com/350/330">-->
```

I tried it in Chrome, Firefox and IE11 and it works fine for me!

**The Fiddle :**

**http://jsfiddle.net/p8nbpt7o/3/**